# Ubuntu Vpn client connected network share through single Ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Please assist how to setup open vpn client connected ubuntu pc to share other network devices through ethernet by separating ethernet port through vlan.

Comment: Are you trying to share VPN access to ethernet devices, or ethernet LAN access to VPN clients, or both? What kind of VPN – managed by the same person/organization or something else? And... How are VLANs involved in this?

Comment: We have open VPN subscription the thing is need  assign some of management staff through our local network by vlan tagging they need getting open certern sites without installing vpn client software